# I want to show series data array in highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I have a `highchart` and currently it shows only one value. I want to show an array of data. This is my current a javascript method and it's only showing one data.

```
$(function () {
    //alert("myValues"+myValues);
    //console.log("deviceName"+deviceName);
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Daily  Power Consumption'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Device : '+deviceName
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickInterval: 3600 * 2000, // two hour
                tickWidth: 0,
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                labels: {
                    align: 'center',
                    x: -3,
                    y: 20,
                    formatter: function() {
                        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', this.value);
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'power ( W )'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                       // return Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', this.x-(1000*3600)) +'-'+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', this.x) +': <b>'+ this.y + '</b>'+this.series.name;
                                         return Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', this.x-(1000*3600)) +'-'+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', this.x) +':'+ this.y + '';
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Time Period',
               // name: deviceName,
                data: [myValues]
            }]
        });
    });
```

But then I need to loop through the arrays somehow, pushing everything into the series data and I don't know how to do that.

If I use a for loop with this data, how do I insert into the `highcharts` series data?

Comment: Can you please add your code to fiddle or code snippet ... also can you print [myValues] so you can be sure that the data is in the correct format

Comment: In order to tell you how to loop through your data and build the appropriate array, we need to see an example of your data. But, to push it to the chart, you do basically what you're doing now, except this: `data: [myvalues]` should become `data: myvalues`, as the brackets are part of the structure of the array that you will build in your loop already.

Comment: this worked data: myvalues thanks